# DNN 9 Persona Bar not visible after login

Tags: authentication, dotnetnuke, persona

I am using DNN 9. I recently upgraded DNN from version 9.1.1 to 9.3.2. When I Login, the left side of DNN disappears with only the logo od DNN. Other options like settings,edit etc are not seen. Any Idea as to what the issue might be?

Answer (score 1):

If you search the forums at dnnsoftware.org, you'll probably find the solution.  I'm afraid that I don't recall what it is.

I think, though, that upgrading to 9.4.4 will fix it, too.  You'll want to do that in a test environment to make sure that your upgrade will work.  There may be some third party modules that need to be upgraded before you upgrade to 9.4.4, so check with module vendors.

Comment: I did upgrade the version to 9.4.4 but it still did not fix the issue. Any other possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to Joe's answer: There were Problems with the Newtonsoft JSON versions. Maybe this thread is helpful: https://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/543186/scope/posts/persona-bar-not-displaying-completely

"...so check with module vendors": There are known issues with DNNSharp modules. See https://dnncommunity.org/forums/aft/748 - but better check with all vendors of third party extensions, if you use any.

Answer (score 0):

Read a few things, tried this and it worked. Delete all from the Bin directory, grab and copy all from another bin directory from a currently working site with the exact version. You may need to install a demo/test site and spin it up to get a good working copy, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Restoring the bin folder was the solution for me